# Changing the color of the Pencil tool

Tags: colors, gimp

I am new to GIMP and I do not understand how to change the color of the Pencil tool. The only options I see are:

- Mode
- Opacity
- Brush
- Dynamics

Where is the option for the color that will be drawn?

Comment: using mac btw if that matters

Comment: Questions like this make it clear how difficult is (not intuitive) to do simple things in GIMP... :(

Answer (score 13, accepted):

At the bottom of the toolbox you see a black and white square. Those are your foreground and background colors. To change them, just click on the square. Also have a look at some Gimp tutorials, as there is certainly plenty of other stuff left to learn:

- http://www.gimp.org/tutorials/

Comment: There is no tutorial on how to draw a line.  BTW: Your answer doesn't work on my system.  No matter what I do, the line doesn't show up and that includes swapping background and foreground between white and black.

Comment: In my case, it was due to my having not noticed the creation of a layer and that layer having been the selected one and also having been occluded by the layer I was trying to draw on.

Answer (score 14):

### Foreground and Background Colors:

[image: tools] [image: tooltip]

Comment: To show the menu above in 2.9.8, go to Windows > New Toolbox.

Answer (score 7):

First make sure you set Image/Mode/RGB

Then click on the black/white squares thing.

Click on the corner black for your tool, it represents the 'top' or 'foreground'.

Comment: There are already two answers from 6 yrs ago that describe this.  This answer doesn't add anything substantively different.

Comment: I put that there and  I did it because the answers didn't mention setting mode RGB and I still couldn't get it to work. I find that substantively different.  What I don't find substantively different or helpful is your comment.

Comment: The other answers didn't mention requiring RGB because it is irrelevant.  It isn't clear why you had difficulty, but that shouldn't have been it.  Perhaps you had an image created with an unusual color space that GIMP had problems with, but color space is not normally a factor for the foreground/background tool.

Comment: Well it was relevant for me.  And therefore presumably relevant for some others.  Like the one who posted somewhere the advice to do it. Hence perfectly valid to post the point.  Are you the official policeman of posts, then?  Pleased to meet you.  'Bye.

Comment: @arthurbrogard regardless of comments that assert otherwise, your answer *was* helpful to me.

Comment: Thank you for that, René, means a lot to me. I get quite depressed by some responses in some forums cutting right across your bows when you're happily sailing on a sunshiny course, meaning no harm to anyone.
Then suddenly the light seems to go out.
You've switched it back on.  Thanks.  :)

Comment: This response is indeed useful: I did not realize that my image was in gray, and even with a red foreground color, pencil coloring was grey! Obviously makes sense once you realize that!

Comment: Solved the problem for me. Before, I just got shades of gray.